# refresh div once (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

MODS: before you mark as duplicate question, I have looked through other threads and didn't find the answer to my specific situation.

Basically I want to refresh a div once it's loaded.

I have this script, which fits my situation but it refreshes the page every 3 seconds.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
      $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here" );
}, 3000);
});
</script>

<div id="here">dynamic content ?</div>
```

What I'm looking for is to refresh Just **ONCE** after it's loaded.

I know there's something I'm missing.

If anyone knowledgeable could point me what change needs to be made in my code would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: `setInterval()` repeats. `setTimeout()` occurs only once after the specified delay

Comment: What is your dynamic content? Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.